# Database With Users and Images

Tags: database, image

How to form database with users and images and to know every user which images belongs to him. For example if I have in database users with (id=1 name=Peter) and another user (id=2 name=Alex) and etc. ? How to know with FK and PK which images belongs to him, how to form this database ?

Comment: Which type of database are you using ???

Comment: Sounds like your Image table should have a foreign key to UserID. (One to many relationship from users to Images). If each User only has one image, just go ahead and include it in the Users table.

Comment: But what if many users have same images ?

Comment: If it's something like the User choosing an Avatar from your list of Avatar's, then it should be the other way around. You didn't really provide enough information for me to determine that. Can you give some more information about what you are using this for?

Comment: I want to create web application with users and every user to have as many images as he want. If i sign in with one user I want to have his own images if I sign in with another user this another user to have his own images and all these images to be saved in user profiles. The problem is that i don't know how to form the database to keep which users which images he/she has.

Comment: In that case, go with my first recommendation. Like the guy below suggested, just store the path to the image in the database rather than the image itself. Since it's a web application, you can display those images by just putting the absolute path that you query for in an IMG tag.

Comment: I have an idea when user is registered a new folder with his username to be created and in this folder to list all images who belongs to him and in database users will have table field with the path to the specific folder. For example if I have 10 users in the database it will automatically create 10 folders. What do you think about this idea ?

Comment: That's a perfectly fine solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to store the location of the images in the database using VARCHAR datatype instead of any BLOB or other binary datatype.So you can use a column for ImageUrl Or path no need to use different table.

Storing the database location reduces the size of database greatly as well updating or replacing the image are much simpler as it is just an file operation instead of massive update/insert/delete in database.

Note:Before saving Image to actual folder don't forget to rename it Because uploaded image can have same name try to use GUID as it Gives unique value.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/13/sql-server-do-not-store-images-in-database-store-location-of-images-url/